# CSS , js , jpg png not loading after using Rewrite rule help me

Tags: javascript, php, css, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I use the following Rewrite rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?:css|js|jpe?g|gif|png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-z_-]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)$ blog.php?cat_nm=$1&tit=$2 [L,NC]

# rewrite css, js and images, from root
RewriteRule ^abc/[^/]+/[^/]+/(.+)$ $1  [L]

RewriteRule ^home$ index.php [NC,L] 

RewriteRule ^([a-z_-]+)$ post.php?u=$1 [NC,L]
```

When open this url:

```
http://www.roominsikar.com/ask/food/payal-food-plaza
```

The `css`, `js` and `img` references don't work.

How can I solve that?

### I Get solution:-

non rewrite url is:-

```
http://www.example.com/blog.php?cat_nm=food&tit=payal-food-plaza
```

this url based on

```
http://www.example.com/blog.php
```

so i am simply put in head section on top  like this
:-

```
<base href="http://www.example/blog.php">
```

than css, js img work fine this url

```
http://www.example.com/blog/food&/payal-food-plaza
```

you will get solution  put only one tag

Comment: please do that i need @trincot

Comment: curious if Chris' answer solved this question. If it did, consider accepting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I Get solution:**-

non rewrite url is:-

```
 http://www.example.com/blog.php?cat_nm=food&tit=payal-food-plaza
```

this url based on

```
http://www.example.com/blog.php
```

so i am simply put in head section on top like this :-

```
<base href="http://www.example/blog.php">
```

than css, js img work fine this url

```
http://www.example.com/blog/food&/payal-food-plaza
```

you will get solution put only one tag

Answer (score 0):

Your resources are all relatively linked:

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

so your browser makes the requests to the domain + current path + the resource:

```
http://www.roominsikar.com/ask/food/payal-food-plaza/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

make the resources absolutely linked:

```
<link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

and it will map to the domain + the resource:

```
http://www.roominsikar.com/css/bootstrap.min.css
```